# How to build library with WPF forms

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, window

Is it possible to build a **Class Library** dll which also includes WPF forms?
When I try to build one I get following errors:

> Error 1 Library project file cannot specify `ApplicationDefinition` element.
>   Error 2 The project file contains a property value that is not valid.

If I set my project as **Windows Application** it compiles & runs tho. Is there a way to get arround this? I'm using VS2010 & C# .NET 4.0 if that might be of any interest to you guys.

Thanks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Choose `WPF Custom Control Library` or `WPF User Control Library` when creating/adding new project to your solution.

Comment: Actually it's more of a mixed library. It contains regular classes and functionalities, together with some forms. Will that work?

Comment: Is there any way of doing this AFTER I already created it as a normal Class Library? I'm looking at it's properties but neither WPF Custom Control Library or WPF User Control Library can be picked from there..

Comment: Yes, to get rid of this error, select App.xaml in your solution explorer and delete it.

Comment: I already have a solution with several projects. The project to which I've added the WPF Form doesn't haven an App.xaml file..

Comment: There must be a file in your project whose `Build Action` is set to `ApplicationDefinition`. You have to remove that file or change its `Build Action`.

Comment: @deycyclone, by the upvotes, that `Build Action` must work for some people.  But not for me -- after all it contradicts error #1 in the OP.  Mikl X's advice worked fine for me.

Answer (score 30):

Change the build action of your `UserControl` from `ApplicationDefinition` to `Page`.

Comment: This was the the problem for me. If any of my .xaml files in a project are ApplicationDefinition for the build action I get this error.

Comment: By default, App.xaml will have the Build Actions set to ApplicationDefinition.

Comment: App.xaml has to be changed from ApplicationDefinition to Page then solved +1

Answer (score 11):

Remove the App.xaml and App.xaml.cs in your WPF Project. Then you will be able to run the project with an output type of Class Library.

Comment: Ran into this after creating a Wix Custom BA, then changing the WPF project from Application to Class Library. Deleted the App.xaml.* files, then it compiled immediately!

Answer (score 8):

This is also occur when we copy  paste  an Image to ClassLibrary Project.

Change the Build Action Property of that image to resources

Answer (score 2):

[problems after copying XAML controls from WPF Application to class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050588/problems-after-copying-xaml-controls-from-wpf-application-to-class-library)

The first answer work for me.
I changed App.xaml from **ApplicationDefinition** to **Page** and worked

Answer (score 1):

Extending @2493490 answer.

Right click on the app.xaml file and exclude it from the project.
Change the project output type to in project properties to Class Library.
Click on the run icon, the solution will successfully build but will not run/execute any code. A error message will be displayed explaining as such.