# Is it possible for XAML Pages (WPF App) be included in a dll?

Tags: wpf, xaml, dll, compilation

I want to compile a series of **pages** (Xaml as in WPF app) in a **dynamic link library** but it seems that there is some limitation to include them as content and their class as something that should be compiled.
I want them(pages) to read Resources directly from DLL and I use the pages in my application.
1.Is there a way to include them in DLL's?

**For more info**: I should point to the main problem here. I'm writing an app that use to be a plug-able one. the question about the app is:
2. how do I add these pages to extend my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using **Class libraries** instead of **Custom Control library** or **user control library**.

[How to build library with WPF forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436986/how-to-build-library-with-wpf-forms?answertab=active#tab-top)